# Entity Framework Throws Error With Functions on a View

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository, entity-framework-5

I have an repository that has has a method where I can pass functions to further query the data, for example;

```
List<Household> households = repository.AllIncluding(i => i.Id == "1419683").ToList();
```

When I connect to a table this call works but when I connect to a View it throws the following error: **The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.**

I thought it maybe be related to the relationships I have on the table but even when I query the Id (I know I can use find) it still throws the error. Please help!?

Here is my method in full:

```
    public virtual IQueryable<Household> AllIncluding(params Expression<Func<Household, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<Household> query = _dbContext.Households;
        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }
        return query;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
List<Household> households = repository.AllIncluding(i => i.Id == "1419683").ToList();
```

just try this

```
var households = repository.AllIncluding().Where(i => i.Id == "1419683").ToList();
```

Another thing is that `.Include` accepts navigation properties which means linked tables. For example if you have `scooters` as linked entities then you could do something like this

```
var households = repository.AllIncluding(x => x.Scooters).Where(i => i.Id == "1419683").ToList();
```